# Crumbling Cookies with jQuery

Tags: jquery, cookies

Here is what i want to do - run a series of jQuery animations the first time someone visits my website.

I want to do this using standard jQuery calls for the animation and the [jQuery Cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) to log whether they have visited before.

Most of what i want is working with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.cookie('visited', 'no', { expires: 14 });
    var visited = jQuery.cookie('visited');
    if (visited == 'no') {
         jQuery("#navigation-wrap").delay(500).animate({ 
      marginLeft: "0px"
      }, 500 );
   jQuery('.page-navigation').delay(1000).slideToggle(400);
   jQuery('.page-navigation').delay(1000).slideUp(300);
   jQuery("#navigation-wrap").delay(2000).animate({ 
      marginLeft: "-180px"
      }, 500 );     
       }
     jQuery.cookie('visited', 'yes');
 });
</script>
```

But, even though the Cookie value *is* being changed to 'yes' after a visit, the animations still run if I refresh the page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kevin for pointing this out and to @Johnnyb on [CSS-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/11282/cookie-activated-jquery/)

This code does as required:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var visited = jQuery.cookie('visited');
        if (visited == 'yes') {
            return false;
        } else {
             jQuery("#navigation-wrap").delay(500).animate({ 
          marginLeft: "0px"
          }, 500 );
       jQuery('.page-navigation').delay(1000).slideToggle(400);
       jQuery('.page-navigation').delay(1000).slideUp(300);
       jQuery("#navigation-wrap").delay(2000).animate({ 
          marginLeft: "-180px"
          }, 500 );     
           }
         jQuery.cookie('visited', 'yes', { expires: 7 });
     });
 </script>
```

Thanks for your help, guys!

Answer (score 4):

You are setting the cookie back to 'no' every time the page reloads with this line:

`jQuery.cookie('visited', 'no', { expires: 14 });`

Then when your `if` statement checks if the value is 'no' it returns true because you literally changed it to 'no' 2 lines above.

You will have to check for the existence of the cookie first and then place it.

**Example**

As soon as jQuery fires the ready event of the document you execute the following piece of code:

`jQuery.cookie('visited', 'no', { expires: 14 });`

This sets the `visited` cookie to the value `'no'`. After you've set the cookie you retrieve it and check if the value is equal to `'no'`, which it now is.

```
var visited = jQuery.cookie('visited');
if (visited == 'no') {
    ...
}
```

And after the `if` statement you set the `visited` cookie's value to `'yes'`. But as soon as you reload the page we're back at step one again because the `visited` cookie's value is set back to the value `'no'`.

Comment: Ok - cheers! I am not sure exactly what you mean - do you have an example piece of code?

Comment: @Infocentre I will give you an example tommorow because I'm currently on my mobile :).